# Python - Best Course for producing Geodatabase , Visualization and Geoanalysis

Tags: python, geopandas

I'm working on an exercise to plot the offshore wind farms in North Europe and extracting data from it.

I'm trying to find a python module(s) that is suitable for that, and I would also like to get some direction from you if possible on the course of action required to achieve some of the required functions.

Heres a summary of the required functions:

- Using excel, I'll be importing the wind farm names and locations using longitude and latitude info(since this is offshore wind farms, the data will be plotted on the sea, ie. not inland)
- Based on the imported data, hopefully, we can visualize the data using python.
- once the data is plotted, I want to be able to extract data such as:

  1. count of windmills between specified coordinates[longitude(A) and Longitude (B) and/or Latitude(X) and Latitude (Y) ]
  2. Listing of windfarm names between a specified range of coordinates
  3. I want to be able to plot geographical density maps of the farms (or choropleth maps)
  4. Plots showing the number of farms across the globe (perhaps x coordinate being the longitudinal location across the globe, and Y being the number of farms)

Based on the initial research I have made, I have come across geopandas as a suitable option (along with its dependent libraries) however, I could not find sufficient info or tutorial for beginner programmers with a similar working example as the task I am undertaking.

Anyhow, my specific questions are:

1. Is geopandas suitable for the functions I am trying to program
2. Any other libraries or software you would recommend?  (maybe even outside python such as an application)
3. Where can I find a worldmap shapefile that is importable to geopandas
4. are there good geopandas tutorials (or other tutorials) that you would recommend for beginner programmers that are relevant to my task?
5. Any general recommendation to set me on the right course with regard to this task

Your feedback is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, you should be able to do all above in GeoPandas. You should not need anything else. You may even want to use pandas instead of Excel to keep everything in python.
2. You could do the same with any kind of GIS software like QGIS or ArcMap/ArcPro or using `sf` in R. If you are not familiar with python or R, I would probably recommend using QGIS. If you are asking for other libraries in python, I think geopandas is your best shot.
3. Natural earth data is embedded in geopandas. You can load it using `gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))`.
4. This is introduction, with GIS flavour: https://geo-python.github.io/site/. This is GIS-based course, quite nice as well: https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/2018/ And, of course, geopandas.org.

Google specific tasks, there is plenty of resources for steps you need to make.